# Transportation algorithm

Tags: linear-programming

I am attempting Q17 on this worksheet:
http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~qb204/teaching/ex_optim_2.pdf

Am i correct in reformulating the problem as :
minimise $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} tij $ ?
But I don't understand what constraints there need to be. Also in b) it gives me a matrix but to use the transportation algorithm I beloieve I need to be given supplies and demands?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all you have to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \color{red}{x_{ij}} \cdot t_{ij} $, where 

$x_{ij}=\begin{cases} \text{1 , if taxi i pick up costumer j} \\ \text{0, if taxi i doesn´t pick up costumer j}\end{cases}$ The values of $t_{ij}$ are fixed. That are the values of the matrix. Is that comprehensible ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . Yes, I understand that, but I am still unsure how to solve the problem. I am trying to use tableaus to solve this but I don't know if this is the right way to go...

Comment: I don´t know which method you are supposed to use. One method is the [Northwest Corner Method](https://www.linearprogramming.info/northwest-corner-method-transportation-algorithm-in-linear-programming/). Which method do you think of?

Comment: But I don't have the supplies or demands, so how can I apply these methods?

Comment: The supply is 1 for every taxi $i$: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^4 x_{ij}=1  \ \forall \ \  i \in \{1,2,3,4 \}$. And the demand is 1 as well for every costumer $j$:  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_{ij}=1 \ \forall j \in \{1,2,3,4 \}$.

Comment: I see, but this does not give me 7 basic variables

Comment: Why do you need 7 basic variables? And please tell me what kind of method you are supposed to use?

Comment: I am trying to apply the transportation algorithm but I don't think it works

Comment: Putting all the information in a tableau I get only 4 basic variables (since I am only allowed to place 1 in each column and row once

Comment: I hope this makes sense

Comment: 1) What is the transportation algorithm in your opinion? [Here](http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/publication_5_13740_1426.pdf) are several methods provided. 2) Yes, I´ve got 4 basic variables as well.

Comment: I thought I required 7 basic variables for the method to work. Can I just assign 4 of the multipliers the value 0?

Comment: Which method? Please provide a reference.

Comment: On page 2 of your document: "Thus, the model has m + n - 1 independent
constraint equations, which means that the starting basic solution consists of m + n- 1
basic variables"

Comment: I would suggest that you try one of the three methods and show it by making an edit of your question. It doesn´t make sense to talk theoretically about the exercise.